# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Tags: python, windows, python-curses

I am using windows and would like to use the curses package,I installed it with the command:

```
pip install windows-curses
```

but when I try to `import curses`
it gives an eror from the python source file

```
__init__.py
```

here's the eror:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\snake\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/curses/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\curses\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

Can someone please help me fix it?

Comment: Linked question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72433839/14141223