# ModuleNotFoundError: when importing curses in IDE

Tags: python, python-curses

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'` every time I try to uses `curses` in VS Code or PyCharm.

But it works in the command prompt (I'm on Windows BTW)

Code is from Tech With Tim tutorial:

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper
import queue
import time



def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Hello world')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()


wrapper(main)
```

Comment: pip install curses?

Comment: Is curses a library you created? or something you installed?

Comment: pycharm will manage python environments for you. Try creating a requirements.txt file and pycharm should use it

Comment: I've already installed curses.

Comment: Linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70861241/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-curses

Answer (score 1):

If it works in command prompt, you may need to fix your environment to use the correct Python version. Try:

1. Installing [`curses`](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/windows-curses#python-curses-wheels-for-windows):

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Or for Python 3 explicitly

```
pip3 install windows-curses
```

2. Configure your VS-Code interpreter. Open VS code and click <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> then type `select python interpreter` and click on the correct one. I'm not sure how to do this on Pycharm

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: No worries @Luke, what part fixed it? was it part 1 or 2?

Comment: Part 2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Pycharm an environment is used to manage your librarys. To install curses go to settings, Python Interpreter and then an the plus, like this:
[image]

Then install curses